# Laravel error: Cannot redeclare function in class

Tags: laravel, mailing

I am using Laravel and it is giving me this kind of error:

> "Cannot redeclare PinoiseDigitalStudio\Http\Controllers\MailController::store() in MailController.php (line 17)"

This is my Controller

```
namespace PinoiseDigitalStudio\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MailController extends Controller {

    public function store(ContactFormRequest $request){
        return \Redirect::route('contact')->with('message', 'Thanks for contacting us!');
    }

    public function store(ContactFormRequest $request){
        \Mail::send('emails.contact',
            array(
                'name' => $request->get('name'),
                'email' => $request->get('email'),
                'user_message' => $request->get('message')
            ), function($message){
                $message->from('wj@wjgilmore.com');
                $message->to('wj@wjgilmore.com', 'Admin')->subject('TODOParrot Feedback');
        });
        return \Redirect::route('contact')->with('message', 'Thanks for contacting us!');
    }

}
```

Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: pasted old title into question, tabbed/condensed code block, asked an actual question, put error in a quote block, reworded title

Answer (score 0):

You have two methods in your controller with the same name - you can't have two methods called `store`. Rename one of them to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the store method twice:

One redirecting to 'contact' route and another sending the contact email.

You cannot have two methods with the same name in the same class. You need to rename one of the methods

Answer (score 0):

You have two methods for **store** so one method name rename in controller and also rename in route file and try it.